# Assembling a long string with parameters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to assemble a longer SQL string across multiple lines in python 2.7 with parameters, similar to:

```
duration_sql = "select MessageTime, " + \
"Value from [%s] " + \
"where Subsystem=%s and " + \
"Field=%s " + \
"and MessageTime > %s and " + \
"MessageTime < %s" % (i, j, k, l, m)
```

but I get a run-time error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

If I allow it to be one long string without line breaks it works fine. Any way I can break a long string across lines with parameters? Can't figure out the secret sauce...

Comment: Note that it's generally a bad idea to use Python's native string formatting in order to insert parameters into your sql query. This can leave you vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Whenever possible, use the parameterization facilities provided by whatever library you're using to talk to the database.

Comment: Very good idea, Kevin. I have it in my comments to watch out for that, I supposed I should follow my own suggestions... I was rather hoping to create the string and then enter it into the execute() function for pymssql and add the parameters there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
duration_sql = ("select MessageTime, "
    "Value from [%s] "
    "where Subsystem=%s and "
    "Field=%s "
    "and MessageTime > %s and "
    "MessageTime < %s") % (i, j, k, l, m)
```

With parentheses around them, you don't need the `+` and the `\` to combine strings: all the adjacent string literals get combined into one string literal.

(Also, see Kevin's comment about not using string formatting to insert variables into database queries.)

Answer (score 6):

that's because `%` only applies to the last string:

```
"MessageTime < %s" % (i, j, k, l, m)
```

parenthesize your strings you'll be fine

```
duration_sql = ("select MessageTime, " + \
"Value from [%s] " + \
"where Subsystem=%s and " + \
"Field=%s " + \
"and MessageTime > %s and " + \
"MessageTime < %s") % (i, j, k, l, m)
```

also python 2.7 allows to use `format` which is far better (and I'm not even talking about positional/named references that `str.format` offers, see https://pyformat.info/)

```
duration_sql = ("select MessageTime, " +
"Value from [{}] " +
"where Subsystem={} and " +
"Field={} " +
"and MessageTime > {} and " +
"MessageTime < {}").format(i, j, k, l, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to change the " to """

```
duration_sql = """select MessageTime,
Value from [%s]
where Subsystem=%s and
Field=%s
and MessageTime > %s and
MessageTime < %s""" % (i, j, k, l, m)
```

And as other answers have said that you might want to avoid string formatting for SQL query, it can expose you to SQL injection

Comment: @Omortis well, to me this is the cleanest way to do it. you don't have +\ at the end and it's still one string, no string combination.

Comment: This was a good excuse to learn pymssql's parameter insertion style so I went for it.